# Find the interval to which a variable in a trigonometric function belongs.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Consider $f\left(x\right)=\tan\left(\frac{3x-\pi }{2}\right)$. Knowing that: $$k\:\in ]0,2\pi] $$
$$\forall x,\:x+k\in \text{Dom}_f,\:f\left(x\right)=f\left(x+k\right)$$

How can we find over which interval $k$ can be found?

Comment: This is merely a complicated way of asking for the period of the function. You are not looking for an interval, you are looking for the specific value of $k$ which equals the period of the function.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't quite understand how to solve this. Would you mind exemplifying?

Comment: Do you know what the period of the tangent function is?

Comment: [0, pi/2[U]pi/2, pi] I believe.

Comment: Yes, that set contains one complete cycle of the tangent graph. This particular exercise would be easier, however, if you used the fact that one complete cycle of the tangent graph lies on the interval $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: And the period is found by subtracting the left endpoint of the interval from the right endpoint. S0 $P=\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pi$. The period of the tangent function is $P=\pi$.

Comment: Right, and correct me if I'm wrong: the period of this function in particular is $\frac{2\pi }{3}$. The proposed solution for this problem is $]\frac{\pi }{2},\:\frac{3\pi }{4}[$, and I just can't understand why...

Comment: That interval makes no sense to me either. $f(x)=f(x+k)$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of the period and $x$ is in the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

To find the period of

$$ f\left(x\right)=\tan\left(\frac{3x-\pi }{2}\right) $$

one must solve the inequality

$$ -\frac{\pi}{2}<\frac{3x-\pi }{2}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

for $x$.

You will obtain a double inequality of the form

$$ a<x<b$$

and the period $k$ will be found by

$$k=b-a$$

Can you do that? What value do you get for $k$?